# What's the purpose of these redirections and file descriptors?

Tags: bash, shell

I saw the following shell script.  I think I get the basic idea of what it is doing, but I still do not understand what is the purpose of using so many redirections and file descriptors? For example, `exec 3>&1`, `do something 2>&1 1>&3` and `exec 3>&-`.

```
#-Open file descriptor (fd)
exec 3>&1

#-Create a form and then store data to $VALUES variable
VALUES=$(dialog \
    --keep-tite \
    --ok-label "Submit" \
    --backtitle "Linux User Managment" \
    --title "Useradd" \
    --form "Create a new user" \
    15 50 0 \
    "Username:" 1 1 "$user"     1 10 10 0 \
    "Shell:"    2 1 "$shell"    2 10 15 0 \
    "Group:"    3 1 "$groups"   3 10 8 0 \
    "HOME:"     4 1 "$home"     4 10 40 0 \
2>&1 1>&3)

# close fd
exec 3>&-

# display values just entered
echo "$VALUES"
```

Could you please tell me why they are necessary? Is it because the `dialog` utility that is being used? I ask because I've never seen people doing this in simple commands, like `ls` etc.

```
exec 3>&1
ls 2>&1 1>&3
exec 3>&-
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally `dialog` displays its dialog box to the user through `stdout`, which is file descriptor 1, reads the user's keystrokes from `stdin`, which is file descriptor 0, and outputs the values filled in by the user to `stderr`, which is file descriptor 2.

The reason for bringing in an extra file descriptor is to read the values through `$(command…)` substitution (same as backquotes). Command substitution takes whatever the inner command (in this case, `dialog…`) sent to its `stdout` and fills it into the outer command (in this case, `VALUES=…`).

The `2>&1` redirection makes `dialog` send the field values to its `stdout`, where they will be captured into `VALUES`. So, `dialog` needs a different file descriptor to display the dialog box to the user. The `exec 3>&1` duplicates the original `stdout` file descriptor. That is, after that command, file descriptor 3 and file descriptor 1 refer to the same file—the original `stdout`. The `1>&3` redirection makes `dialog` display its dialog to that original `stdout`.

To put that another way, the reason for bringing in file descriptor 3 is to temporarily "save" `stdout`.

Answer (score 4):

The breakdown is simple:

```
exec 3>&1
```

Anything written to file descriptor 3 will go the same place as file descriptor 1, standard output.

```
VALUES=$(command ...arguments... 2>&1 1>&3)
```

Here, anything written to file descriptor 2, standard error, will go the same place as file descriptor 1, standard output.  However, the definition of standard output is then changed so that anything written to standard output goes to the same place as file descriptor 3.  This is inside a command substitution `$(...)` operation, so the standard output is normally captured in a file.  It means that the variable `VALUES` gets to hold whatever the `command` writes to standard error, while the original standard output gets whatever the command writes to standard output.

Finally:

```
exec 3>&-
```

closes file descriptor 3; attempts to write to it will fail from here on.

Your simulation of the command should be:

```
exec 3>&1
variable=$(ls 2>&1 1>&3)
exec 3>&-
```

This would capture any errors from `ls` in `$variable`, while allowing you to see whatever `ls` wrote on standard output.  You don't see this sort of thing done normally because the requirements are a bit unusual.

Comment: +1, though "simple" is a bit of a stretch :) By `so the standard output is normally captured in a file`, did you mean captured in a _variable_?

Comment: 'Simple' is in the eye of the beholder; maybe I meant 'relatively straight-forward but not entirely obvious'.  I also debated about 'file' vs 'variable'; the output goes to a file descriptor, which is a file of some sort, and the data from that is read (on a file descriptor of some sort) and the result of the read operation is saved into the variable.  So yes to both 'file' and 'variable'.